# cs cart file structure

Tags: cs-cart

I want to learn the cs-cart file structure.

I want to make changes to the admin side functionality, can you guide me to where can I read the file structure and the functionality of files.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague which is why there isn't much interest in giving you an answer.

Specifically what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in /skins/your_skin/admin/common_templates to find templates.

If you know what you want to change e.g. last viewed items, do a global search for last_viewed_items.tpl and you'll find it is used in \shop\controllers\admin\tools.php and a number of other places.

You are just going to have to keep digging and if it were me, I would draw some sort of flow chart as I went.

Of course, once you have discovered how it all pieces together you are going to post your results here for others to discover...right?